Layout Inflater Fragment to View how(to) or when does the associated Java file get called?
I created a secondary Activity and also a new Fragment via the menu options. I'm calling
LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater()
inf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reuse_view,this.findViewById(R.id.ReuseViewLayoutLinear))

Which works however it doesn't call any event from the java file. I'm assuming this is not how it works. I have tried Fragment manager but keep getting errors of add(??,??) not compatible.
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ReuseViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ReuseView" >


    //And this is In my New Activity
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ReuseViewLayoutLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

I have tried various methods using the inflator and fragment manager. I simply wish to add a fragment to a Linear View and have that fragments associated java called when it is added to the view.

You need to use FragmentManager. I suggest you try to understand the error it is giving you and take a look at the docs about adding fragment programmatically

Answering my own question and I don't know if this is best practice but I called:
View rv = new ReuseView().onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(),this.findViewById(R.id.ReuseViewLayoutLinear),savedInstanceState);

((LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.ReuseViewLayoutLinear)).addView(rv);
